# Parameter is not valid when selecting image from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm facing an issue when trying to select an image field from the SQL server.

Here's the select code:

```
string cmd = String.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {0}", DefTableNames.Employees.ToString());

DataTable data = SQLDataQueryToTable(FullServerPath(), cmd);

CurrentEditingIndex = int.Parse(data.Rows[0][0].ToString());
empNameDropDown.SelectedItem = empNameDropDown.Items[0];
empNameTxt.Texts = data.Rows[0][1].ToString();
empIdTxt.Texts = data.Rows[0][2].ToString();
empPhoneTxt.Texts = data.Rows[0][3].ToString();
empEducationTxt.Texts = data.Rows[0][4].ToString();
empJobNameTxt.Texts = data.Rows[0][5].ToString();
TextTools.Currencize(data.Rows[0][6].ToString(), empTotalAllTxt);
empAboutTxt.Texts = data.Rows[0][7].ToString();
empBirthDatePicker.Value = DateTime.Parse(data.Rows[0][8].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
empJobDatePicker.Value = DateTime.Parse(data.Rows[0][9].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(data.Rows[0][10]);

image_employeeimage.Image = byteArrayToImage((byte[])data.Rows[0][10], null);

if (image_employeeimage.Image != null)
{
    buttonDeleteImage.Enabled = true;
    buttonDeleteImage.BackColor = Color.Brown;
}
else
{
    buttonDeleteImage.Enabled = false;
    buttonDeleteImage.BackColor = AColors.DisabledColor;
}

empUserDropDown.SelectedItem = data.Rows[0][11].ToString();
```

The code fills everything in properly, however, it keeps stopping at the method for conversion of the data to an image.

Here's the conversion code:

```
public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn, Image defaultImage = null)
{
    if (byteArrayIn == null)
    {
        return defaultImage;
    }

    Image returnImage;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
        returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    return returnImage;
}
```

The code stops exactly at here:

[image]

Here's the code that converts to `byte[]`:

```
    public static byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

When I try to do a `Console.WriteLine` for the value of the image, I get the proper value. Which is `System.Byte[]`.

The type of column in the database is set to `VarBinary`.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why are you injecting a value into your SQL statement for the table name?

Comment: This data access code is, frankly, terrible. Please look into things like Dapper to give you structured access to data without hard-coding things like column indexes, or going through a (very memory-inefficient) `DataTable` first. And `SELECT *` in production code is also seldom a good idea -- be explicit about what columns you're expecting, that way your code won't (silently) break if the table structure changes.

Comment: @Larnu It's just an enum containing the names of tables. So I don't make typos.

Comment: But why inject at all? The fact you need to dynamic reference your tables suggests a design flaw unto itself.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn What do you mean? The select statement I'm doing is basically this:

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees

There isn't one table per employee

Comment: With all due respect guys, I'm only here to fix the image problem, not to refactor my entire code. Thank you.

Comment: You should look inside the byte array and make sure it's not, say, empty. From there try writing it to disk in a file with the correct extension and see if the file opens. Also, add me to the list of those who think this data access pattern is going to get you into trouble. `SQLDataQueryToTable()` looks like it will force you to write code that's crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection issues... the kind of thing where a year from now you find out you were hacked six months ago and all your data is for sale on the dark web. It really is that big a deal which is why we all bring it up.

Comment: The problem seems simple enough: the fact that you have a `byte[]` does not prove that `byte[]` actually contains valid image data. Eliminate the database as the source of trouble first by digging into the contents of the field separately ([`CONVERT(VARCHAR(...), 2)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles), `BitConverter.ToString(...)`).

Comment: @Larnu I don't understand what you mean.

What I'm doing is basically as if I'm writing SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Okay, I'll try that and see what's happening. Thanks

Comment: But why are you not writing `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees`? Why are you creating an injection vector?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I know what SQL Injection is, and I know the consequences and I know I'm supposed to use parameterized queries. But this is not the topic at hand. Thank you.

Comment: @Larnu It might be scuffed, but what I'm doing is basically making sure I'm not writing a typo within the name of the table. It's as if I'm taking the name from a dictionary.

Comment: An SQL query string built from a source that can't be compromised will not cause a vulnerability. If the table name is a string constant, then it's safe. An injection attack depends on data being compromisable. (Though I'd prefer string interpolation over Format in this case.)

Comment: @BentTranberg I'll look into the interpolation. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: I found the problem. Posted in answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem. The issue was pretty dumb:

```
    public static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

I was saving the image as a gif. Which when I changed to this:

```
    public static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Fixed the entire issue.

And I also found a big problem in the save code. I was defining the size of the data as 255. This also led to the images not loading at times or loading as null. This was in the original code that I didn't share:

```
        if(image_employeeimage.Image == null)
        {
            sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 255)); sqlParams[9].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 255)); sqlParams[9].Value = imageToByteArray(image_employeeimage.Image);
        }
```

I simply removed 255.

Everything seems fine now. Thanks a lot for the help everyone, and thanks for the tips on my code.

If there are any comments on my fix, please share them.